# Next Js Image 'fill' prop, image not displaying

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, css-grid, nextjs-image

Working on a simple grid with images and text. using Next 13.4.7 and tailwind, But when I try to import the image using the Next Image component and using the fill prop the image doesn't render.

```
return (
        <button className="relative group flex items-center rounded-md overflow-hidden gap-x-4 bg-neutral-100/10 hover:bg-neutral-100/20 pr-4 transition">
            <div className="relative min-h-[64px] min-w -[64px]">
                <Image className="object-cover" fill src={image} alt="Image" />
            </div>
            <p>
                {name}
            </p>
        </button>
    );
```

I have tried explicitly defining fill to true

`fill = {true}`

And that didn't work either.

But it seems to respond to swapping fill for height and width props

```
<Image className="object-cover" width={64} height={64} src={image} alt="Liked Playlist" />
```

Does anyone have an Idea on why that's happening? or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image

According to the official page ***src***, ***width***, ***height*** and ***alt*** must be included in the `<Image/>` tag... then you can use **fill={true}** with it otherwise it will not work.

Comment: You are trying to say to use the `fill` property `height` and `width` must be included but as far as I understand it is the exact opposite. The documentation provided says: "A boolean that causes the image to fill the parent element instead of setting `width` and `height`." Can you please recheck and let me know if I am wrong?

Comment: no.. width,height ,src,alt are compulsory  and fill is not compulsory

Comment: <div>
      <div style={{width: '64px', height: '64px', position: 'relative'}}>
        <Image src={image} layout='fill' alt='loading'/>
      </div>
check it..it is work or not

Comment: The `fill` prop is used to substitute (for a lack of better work) the function of `width` and `height`. They can not be used together.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is really really simple. See when you use `fill` prop it *fills* the parent div. It seems like you have given an extra space when defining the width of parent div. Try this and it should work:

```
return (
        <button className="relative group flex items-center rounded-md overflow-hidden gap-x-4 bg-neutral-100/10 hover:bg-neutral-100/20 pr-4 transition">
            <div className="relative min-h-[64px] min-w-[64px]">
                <Image className="object-cover" fill src={image} alt="Image" />
            </div>
            <p>
                {name}
            </p>
        </button>
    );
```